# cell expand in tableview is not showing properly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift I have a `tableView` with a custom cell. When I hit the cell, it should expand the cell and show all the data. I tried but I am not able to get the proper result. I have to show a custom table view cell when I will show all the data
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn1GM.png). I have the data coming from json.

Custom xib table view cell:

```
class ExpandTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLable: UILabel!

    var item: ExpandTableViewCell?  {
        didSet {
        }
    }

    static var nib:UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
    }

    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

}
```

Register into the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView?.register(ExpandTableViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: ExpandTableViewCell.identifier)
```

The `tableView` methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 1 {
        if  storeDetailsDictionary != nil{
            return (storeDetailsDictionary?.count)!
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.section == 1) {
        //address cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ExpandTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ExpandTableViewCell
        var timing:String = String.init(htmlEncodedString: storeDetailsDictionary!["timing"] as? String ?? "")
        cell?.timeLable.text = timing//?.replacingOccurrences(of:", ", with: ",\n")

        return cell!
    }
}
```

How can I expand the table view cell?

Comment: None of the code that you are showing would work for expanding a cell. Please show what you have tried so people here can help you find the error.

Answer (score 0):

check this tutorial it's helpful for creating expandable list:
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-collapsible-sections-96badf3387d0